# Cargar dinamicamente editor tinymce 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

llevo varios días con este problema lo que deseo es cargar a través de de la función get de jquery de la siguiente manera.

```
$('.panel-group').on('click','.notification',function(){
    var Form = $(this).data('form');
    var Content = $(this).parent().next().find('.panel-body');
    $.get(Form,function(data){
        Content.html(data);
        tinyMCE.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor',false,'#body-notification');
    });
});
```

estoy usando la versión 4 de la librería

Comment: Que error te marca? ya intentaste con la función `init()`

Comment: Si con init tambien he hecho la prueba no me marca ningún error simplemente no le asigna el editor al textarea no se que mas pueda hacer

Comment: Puede ser por la forma asincróna de la llamda, intenta meter el tinyMCE en una función de tiempo `setTimeout`

Comment: mmmm eso lo coloco luego del get o después del html

Comment: Si, tienes que meterlo en el get